# Does conservativeResize() re-Allocate Each Time?

Tags: eigen

When using `Eigen::PlainObjectBase::conservativeResize()` for changing the number of rows repeatedly, does it reallocate the memory for each call, or only when there is not enough [internal] capacity?

Comment: Are you looking to [reshape a matrix](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialReshapeSlicing.html#TutorialReshape)?

Comment: Yes, dynamically change the number of rows, without re-allocating (if it is smaller than previously).

Comment: Then reading the page I linked, the answer is not really. You can use `matrix.topRows(n)` or other block operations, but that's really it. Or you can just re-use the memory with a Map, but that doesn't last longer than the scope of the map (the original matrix data is changed, of course, but not the dimensions).

Comment: OK, that's what I thought. Thanks!

Comment: If you want resizing without re-allocation, have a look at this pending PR: https://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/pull-requests/125. Alternatively, as @AviGinsburg suggested, you can allocate a bigger matrix, and access only part of it.

Comment: @chtz that seems relatively old and not moving. I assume it’s not going to be pulled any time soon, am I correct?

Comment: I ended up going with `topRows()` as suggested since I know the maximum number of rows.

Comment: If you actually know the maximum number of rows (and columns) at compile-time, you can even use `Matrix<float, Dynamic, Dynamic, 0, MaxRows, MaxCols>` which will allocate everything on the stack, but that is not recommended, if the size is big (like more than a few kilobytes -- though this also depends on the architecture/OS/... you are using). For `.topRows()` you may consider using `Eigen::RowMajor` as 4th template argument to your matrix, so you have continuous memory.

Comment: The max size is big and only known at run time (and also significantly larger than the typical actual count). However I’ll look into RowMajor. What is that and is it not the default?